# Manipulating time in python

Tags: python, datetime

In the code shown below, I need to manipulate the time var in python to display a date/time stamp in python to represent that delay.

For example, when the user enters the delay time in hours, I need to set the jcarddeliver var to update itself with the value of the current date/time + delay.

Also it should update the date var as well. For example, if the date is 24 Feb and time is 15:00 hrs and the delay time is 10 hrs, the jcarddeliver date should change to 25 Feb.

```
jcarddate = time.strftime("%a %m/%d/%y", time.localtime())
jcardtime = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime())
delay = raw_input("enter the delay: ")
jcarddeliver = ??
```

I just hope I am making sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the datetime module, e.g.

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
delay = float (raw_input ("enter delay (s): "))
dt = datetime.timedelta (seconds=delay)
then = now + dt
print now
print then
```

Comment: from what i see, the now and then variables can only be displayed correctly using the print module. what if i have to pass these values to the DB. it gives me an error saying, not all arguments converted during string formatting.

Comment: In the above example the variables 'now' and 'then' are datetime objects.  When you print them they're converted to a string.  If you really want a string try the str() function, e.g. str(now).  Of course you can also use now.year, now.month, etc.  More info at http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html.

Answer (score 1):

The result of `time.time()` is a floating point value of the number of seconds since the Epoch. You can add seconds to this value and use `time.localtime()`, `time.ctime()` and other functions to get the result in various forms:

```
>>> now = time.time()
>>> time.ctime(now)
'Fri Sep 04 16:19:59 2009' # <-- this is local time
>>> then = now + (10.0 * 60.0 * 60.0) # <-- 10 hours in seconds
>>> time.ctime(then)
'Sat Sep 05 02:19:59 2009'
```

Comment: I would use Brian's solution (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381315/manipulating-time-in-python/1381769) since the `datetime.timedelta()` usage is considerably clearer.

Answer (score 0):

" i need to set the jcarddeliver var to update itself with the value of the current date/time + delay"

How about reformulating this to

`jcarddeliver` should be the current date-time plus the delay.

The "update itself" isn't perfectly sensible.

Try the following:

1. Try the most obvious way of computing "current date-time plus the delay"
2. print the result.
3. Try using `localtime()` on this result.  What do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
now = time.time()
then = now + 365*24*3600
print time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d', time.localtime(then))
```